# Eagerly load lazy items from Hibernate/JPA and correct object counts

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Data and Hibernate for my web app. I have the following entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Purchase{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Item> items;
    // etc
}
```

I need to eagerly load a number of purchases including their associated items in each purchase. I am using the following JPQL:

```
@Query("select p from Purchase p join fetch p.items where r.id in (:ids)")
List<Purchase> getPurchasersByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

However, the number of returned objects is NOT the number of purchases, but the number of items. For example, if I have only one purchase, which contains two items, then the returned list would contain two objects of the same purchase. How can I make it return only one Purchase object with two eagerly load items?

Comment: Try using Distinct in the query.  "Select Distinct p from .."

Comment: Chris, thanks for chiming in! It generates errors if I add "Distinct"

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is according to spec (unfortunately). See JPA 2.1, ch. 4.4.5.3 "Fetch Joins":

> The following query returns a set of departments. As a side effect, the associated employees for those departments are also retrieved, even though they are not part of the explicit query result. [...]
>
> ```
> SELECT d
> FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees
> WHERE d.deptno = 1
> ```
>
> [...] Hence, for example, if department 1 has five employees, the above query returns five references to the department 1 entity.

Comment: Based on my research, it appears that there is no way to achieve what I want based on what I have.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to return number of p's, try to do select count(p)

Comment: I need to have the list of objects, not the count. If for the object count, then I would not use JPQL.

Comment: Please explain what exactly do you mean by "number of purchases"

Comment: Did you try to use Set instead of List and adding distinct to query?

Comment: I would like to have the list of purchase object without repetition. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use Set instead of List?